# MYSQL Results display wrong when results do not exceed 1 page

Tags: mysql, css

Hi I have a page that I am working on, which takes articles from a database.  the results are split using php and show six articles per page.  The problem i have is that if there are seven results and we roll into page 2, then everything thing is fine as can be seen under the timepieces menu button.

If however there are less than 6 articles and only one page the first article goes funny and the text drops below the image as can be seen under the private aviation button.

A link to the website is here  : http://goo.gl/N8p8CT

Both items appear to be within the article.row.mid and so i am struggling to work out why.

Comment: As I see it happens because first article has <a... link under image.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that, but i have changed it and its no different

Comment: Thanks, if you add it as an answer i will select it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause first article has image wrapped into `<a></a>` tag, but second article hasn't, these two images are rendered by different css rules.
[image]
and
[image]
first one is styled by botstrap.css rules, 2-nd is by your own stylesheet.
Anyway if you use bootstrap, then it's better to wrap image of article into a div for better alignment using bootstrap grid.
I'd do:

```
<article class="row mid">
<div class="col-xs-4">
<a href="https://www.flyvictor.com/?utm_source=display&amp;utm_medium=leaderbanner&amp;utm_campaign=tempus20141010" target="_blank">
                        <img src="admin/images/private_jet_hanger-1413201025.jpg" alt="post1" height="250px" width="250px">
                        </a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-8 info"><a href="https://www.flyvictor.com/?utm_source=display&amp;utm_medium=leaderbanner&amp;utm_campaign=tempus20141010" target="_blank">
                            </a><h1><a href="https://www.flyvictor.com/?utm_source=display&amp;utm_medium=leaderbanner&amp;utm_campaign=tempus20141010" target="_blank"></a><a href="article.php?id=111&amp;tag1=private_aviation">Jet Partner launches empty leg service...</a></h1>
                            <p class="details"></p>
                            <p class="tags"></p>
                            <p class="text">
                                </p><p>The advantages associated with private jet travel are invaluable: the ability to journey in comfort, security and privacy; to arrive at the airport just 15 minutes before take-off and to completely avoid check-in. Now, the advent of groundbreaking                          </p>
                            <a href="article.php?id=111" class="btn btn-default" "="">Read More</a>                         <ul class="counters list-inline">

                            </ul>

                        </div>
                    </article>
```